# request.put() but it request using GET by PUT on my python

Tags: python, http, python-requests, wireshark, put

Even I using `requests.put()`, server recognized its request as "GET".

Here is my code.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://api.domain.com/test/partners/digital-pie/users/assignee'
payload = """
{
"assignee": {
"district": "3",
"phone": "01010001000",
"carNum": "598865"
},
"deduction": {
"min": 1000,
"max": 2000
},
"meta": {
"unit-label": "1-1-1",
"year": "2017",
"quarter": "2"
}
}
"""

headers = {"content-type": "application/json", "x-api-key": "test_api_dp" }

r = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

print("status code:", r.status_code)
print('encoding:', r.encoding)
print('text:', r.text)
print('json:', r.json())
```

When I checked pack by wireshark, I can know my code requested as "GET".

[image: wireshark packet]

Which is wrong with my code?

added more.

I corrected code as below, and I found 302 Redirection occurred by checking r.history.
But still stuck why 302 happened.
When I compared to postman.  It show correctly.

[Comparison with postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Hbj.png)

addition 2nd.
[requests variable watch window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Qay.png)

Comment: `requests.put()` definitely sends a `PUT` method. Are you certain that the server hasn't responded with a `302` or `303` redirect?

Comment: The GET request you show in the screenshot **does not match your request**. The PUT goes to `/test/partners/digital-pie/users/assignee`, the GET is for `/partners/digital-pie/users/assignee`. I also note that the server responded with a 404 to that GET request.

Comment: Side note: there is no need to use `json.dumps()` or set the `Content-Type` header when you use `json=payload` instead of `data`.

Comment: To check for redirects, you can see if `r.history` is non-empty.

Comment: Also, `payload` is **already a JSON string**, which you encoded to JSON *again*. Remove the `json.dumps()` call, or make `payload` a Python dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for all.  I changed code payload. and removed json.dumps().  I added more to description.

Comment: Your Postman screenshot is too limited to tell us much, but I see a 400 Bad Request response in that screenshot, indicating that that request *failed as well*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost certainly being *redirected*. The PUT request *is sent*, but the server responded with a [3xx redirection response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx), which `requests` then follows and issues a GET request for. I note that the path in your wireshark screenshot doesn't match the one used in your code (the `/test` prefix is missing), further adding evidence that a redirection has taken place.

You can check the [redirection history](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) by looking at `r.history` (each entry is another response object), or set `allow_redirects=False` to not respond to redirects (you get the first response, nothing else).

You are probably getting redirected because you are *double-encoding* your JSON payload. There is no need to use `json.dumps` on a string that is *already a JSON document*. You are sending a single JSON string, whose contents happen to be a JSON document. That is almost certainly the wrong thing to send.

Correct this by removing the `json.dumps()` call, or by replacing the `payload` *string* with a *dictionary*:

```
payload = {
    "assignee": {
        "district": "3",
        "phone": "01010001000",
        "carNum": "598865"
    },
    "deduction": {
        "min": 1000,
        "max": 2000
    },
    "meta": {
        "unit-label": "1-1-1",
        "year": "2017",
        "quarter": "2"
    }
}
```

Incidentally, you would be better off then using the `json` keyword argument; you get the `Content-Type: application/json` header as an added bonus:

```
headers = {"x-api-key": "test_api_dp" }    
r = requests.put(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

Again, this assumes that `payload` is a Python data structure, *not* a JSON document in a Python string.

Comment: You're right.  I can find out page redirect.  r.history tell 302 code.
But still I don't know why 302 redirected.  
Compared to postman.  it response correctly.

I guest wireshark doesn't show https packet.

Comment: @sungyong: no, wireshark can't show encrypted data. It probably lists the packets, but can't decrypt the payload to show you HTTP-level information.

Comment: @sungyong: I can't see what payload you are sending. It could be that the redirect body contains more information, inspect `r.history[0].content` perhaps. There may be clues in the headers too. There is not enough info here to be able to diagnose anything, really.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters:  Could you please check my variable watch window attached main description?   As you mentioned, 1st request was PUT, and next was GET.  but r.history[0] is empty.   I still wonder why it is different from postman.

Comment: @sungyong: again, that doesn't tell me anything, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply test what method is using with http://httpbin.org

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.put('http://httpbin.org/anything')
>>> r.content
b'{\n  "args": {}, \n  "data": "", \n  "files": {}, \n  "form": {}, \n  
"headers": {\n    "Accept": "*/*", \n    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
\n    "Connection": "close", \n    "Content-Length": "0", \n    "Host": 
"httpbin.org", \n    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.18.3"\n  }, \n  
"json": null, \n  "method": "PUT", \n  "origin": "91.232.13.2", \n  "url": 
"http://httpbin.org/anything"\n}\n'
```

As you can see method used is PUT

Comment: Yes, the OP is wrong, a PUT request is *always sent* when you use `requests.put()`. The issue is that they are looking at the wrong request in wireshark.